# Involution in $L^{1}(G)$ is isometric.

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

(Sorry for asking so many questions of the same type.  There is an underlying issue that I think once resolved will allow me to understand them all at once.)

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and $f\in L^{1}(G)$.
I'm trying to verify that $\|f^{*}\|_{p} = \|f\|_{p}$, where the involution $*$ is defined by $f^{*}(x) = \delta(x)^{-1}\overline{f(x^{-1})}$.

So my computations so far look like:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{G}f^{*}(y)\mu(dy) &=& \int_{G}\left|\delta(y^{-1})\overline{f(y^{-1})}\right|^{p}\mu(dy)\\
                        &=& \int_{G}\delta(y^{-1})^{p}\left|\overline{f(y^{-1})}\right|^{p}\mu(dy)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Here I am stuck at the central issue I am facing where the calculations stop making sense and I feel like I'm just throwing things around hoping it's true.

How do I use the definition of the $\delta$ map:
$$\text{the unique group homomorphism }\delta:G\to(0,\infty)\text{ such that }\\\delta(x)\mu(E) = \mu(Ex)\text{ for all Borel sets }E$$

when its argument is not independant of the variable of integration?

Ted has already confirmed in his answer to:

**[How to use the modular function of a locally compact group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389680/how-to-use-the-modular-function-of-a-locally-compact-group)**

that the definition of $\delta$ implies:

$$\int_{G}\delta(x)f(y)\mu(dy) = \int_{G}f(y)\mu(dy\cdot x)$$

If I try to use that step in my current problem, I end up with

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{G}\delta(y^{-1})^{p}\left|\overline{f(y^{-1})}\right|^{p}\mu(dy) &=& \int_{G}\left|\overline{f(y^{-1})}\right|^{p}\mu(dy\cdot (y^{-1})^{p})
\end{eqnarray*}
which I don't have any clue how to interpret, and I suspect is wrong.  What is the correct way to handle this function?  I dont know what measure to associate with the notation $\mu(dy\cdot (y^{-1})^{p})$.

I think the answer to this question is what I really need to be able to finish the verifications I'm working on.

Thanks to whoever can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would find the last chapter of *Real Analysis* by Folland helpful (it covers the fundamentals of Haar measures).  The way I think of it, $\delta^{-1}$ is a factor attached to $\mu$ (a left Haar measure), not to $f$. To begin with, the measure $\delta^{-1}\mu$ is right-invariant: 
$$\int_{E\,y}\delta(x)^{-1}\,d\mu(x)=\int_{E}\delta(xy)^{-1}\,\delta(y)\,d\mu(x)= \int_{E}\delta(x)^{-1} \,d\mu(x) $$
And here is another way to get a right invariant measure from $\mu$. 
Let $\iota:G\to G$ be the inversion, $\iota(x)=x^{-1}$. This is an anti-homomorphism, it changes the order of group multiplication. Therefore,  the pushforward $\iota^*\mu$ is a right Haar measure.

**Fact**: $\delta^{-1}\mu =  \iota^*\mu$.

*Proof*. They are both right Haar measures, therefore one is a constant multiple of each other. To see that the multiple must be $1$, consider a symmetric neighborhood of identity, called $U$, which is small enough so that $|\delta(x)^{-1}-1|<\epsilon$ for $x\in U$. (Such $U$ exists because the modular function is continuous.) Now, $\iota^*\mu(U)=\mu(U)$ by symmetry, and also $|\delta^{-1}\mu(U)-\mu(U)|<\epsilon \,\mu(U) $. Since the ratio of $\iota^*\mu(U)$ to $\delta^{-1}\mu(U)$ can be made arbitrarily close to $1$, but is also a constant (independent ot $U$), the ratio is in fact $1$. $\Box$

The rest is a tautology from abstract measure theory: $$\int (f\circ \iota) \,d\mu = \int f \,d (\iota^*\mu) \tag1$$
hence $$\int f(x^{-1})\,d\mu(x) = \int f(x)\,\delta(x)^{-1} \,d\mu(x) \tag2$$
Actually,   you want to put   $f\circ \iota$ instead of $f$ here, so that the result is exactly as required:
$$\int f(x )\,d\mu(x) = \int f(x^{-1})\,\delta(x)^{-1} \,d\mu(x) \tag3$$

---

But I don't think your construction produces an isometry on $L^p$, at least not as stated. The identity (3) immediately generalizes to 
$$\int |f(x )|^p\,d\mu(x) = \int |f(x^{-1})|^{p}\delta(x)^{-1} \,d\mu(x) \tag4$$ but if you rewrite (4) by attaching $\delta^{-1}$ to $f$, it has to be raised to power $1/p$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer.  I will read it tomorrow morning with a fresh pair of eyes.  Just one clarification:

When you say the measure $\lambda:=\delta^{-1}\mu$ is right invariant.  I get confused because $\delta$ is not a set function, so I don't know how to interpret this.  What is the definition of $\lambda(E)$ for Borel subsets $E$ of $X$?

Comment: @Kyle One can multiply a measure $\mu$ by a nonnegative measurable function $f$, and obtain a new measure $\lambda$, namely $\lambda(E)=\int_E f\,d\mu$. This is often denoted $f\mu$, or $f\,d\mu$.

Comment: I think that last fact may have what I needed to understand all of my questions.  so $\delta^{-1}\mu(E) = \int_{G}\delta(y^{-1})\mu(dy)$?  (using my favourite notation..)

Comment: As for the issue, I made a mistake, it's only an isometry on $L^{1}(G)$, turning $L^{1}(G)$ into an involutive Banach Algebra.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, it's the same thing. In everything that involves both functions and measures, mathematical notation is remarkably inconsistent.

Comment: Does the equation (1) hold for any homeomorphism $\iota:G\to G$?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, and for continuous map too (even measurability is enough). It's pretty much the definition of [pushforward measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure).

Comment: So just to confirm: for general measurable $E$, measurable $\iota:G\to G$, $\int_{E}f\circ \iota d\mu = \int_{\iota(E)}fd(\iota^{*}(\mu))$?

Comment: @Kyle No, you have to be careful with images of sets. For example, the sets $[-1,1]$ and $[0,1]$ have the same image under the map $x\mapsto x^2$. But it is true that $\int_{\iota^{-1}(E)}f\circ i\,d\mu = \int_E f\,d(\iota^*\mu)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  That was amazingly helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck once again.  In  the right hand side of (3) $\delta(x)^{-1}$ attached to $\mu$.  But in the definition of $\|f^{*}\|_{1}$, the $\delta(x)^{-1}$ will be attached to $f(x)$.  I suspect the solution is that it doesn't matter and both interpretations yield the same result.  Assuming this is true, my last question (written in my favourite notation) is:

How do we know that $\int_{G}\delta(x)^{-1}f(x)\mu(dx) = \int_{G}f(x)\delta^{-1}\mu(dx)$.

Comment: @Kyle Multiplication is commutative and associative. My remark about attaching a factor was to describe *the way I think of it*.